# How to change attributes of a magento admin form field label

Tags: adminhtml, blocks, forms

I want to change the css class of a admin field's label. As I have found out there is not setter method such as **setLabelHtml**, I am not able to change the class. At last I override the **Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract** class as suggested by 'AlanStorm' in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993597/adding-a-custom-form-element-to-an-adminhtml-form/1996066#1996066). I changed the '**getLabelHtml**' and place the class attribute there and it worked. Is there any other better way to do it ?

Comment: I am sure @alanstorm would have found a better way, if one existed ;)

Comment: If @alanstorm says it should be done that way, you do it. Don't question his authority. :)

Comment: @Marius, In that he did not say anything about changing css of admin field label. In that post he says about overriding a lib/Varien object

Answer (score 2):

At last I have found two answers for my question. I wanted
to change css class of elements inside the `fieldset` of the form.

### 1. First solution

All of the fieldset created inside a form object is using a `renderer` of `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface` for rendering the html as a last step (if one is present).

The default renderer for a fieldset inside a form is `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element` which is extending `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`. Hence it has a template object attached to it. The template for our renderer is `widget/form/renderer/fieldset/element.phtml`.

The steps to change the default behaviour is as follows:

First of all created a renderer class.

```
class Kaushikamdotcom_Moduler_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Renderer extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element {        
    public function __construct() {
               // Setting template for the element
       $this->setTemplate('widget/form/fieldset/renderer/element.phtml');
    }

    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
               // Just returning the html rendered by parent
       return parent::render($element);
        }

    protected function _toHtml() {
               // Specifying location of template file for the renderer
       $template = $this->getTemplate();
       include(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../templates/' . $template);
    }   
}
```

Then I created a template by copying the `element.phtml` from `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/element/renderer/fieldset` to `templates/widget/form/fieldset/renderer/` inside my module folder. The content of that file is:

```
<?php
$_element = $this->getElement();
$_note    = $_element->getNote();
$_trId    = $_element->getHtmlContainerId();
$_class   = $_element->getFieldsetHtmlClass();
?>
<?php if (!$_element->getNoDisplay()): ?>
<tr<?php if($_trId): ?> id="<?php echo $_trId ?>"<?php endif; ?>>
    <?php if ($_element->getType()=='hidden'): ?>
    <td colspan="2" class="hidden"><?php echo trim($_element->getElementHtml()) ?></td>
    <?php else: ?>
    <td class="label<?php echo $_class ? " {$_class}-label" : ''?>">
    <?php 
         $label = '<label for="'.$_element->getHtmlId().'" class="'.$this->getLabelClass().'" >' . $this->escapeHtml($_element->getLabel())
                  . ( $_element->getRequired() ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' . "\n";
        echo trim($label);
     ?>
    </td>
    <td class="<?php echo $_element->hasValueClass() ? $_element->getValueClass() : 'value' ?><?php echo $_class ? " {$_class}-value" : ''?>">
        <?php echo trim($_element->getElementHtml()) ?>
        <?php if ($_note): ?>
            <p class="note<?php echo $_class ? " {$_class}-note" : ''?>" id="note_<?php echo $_element->getId()?>"><span><?php echo $_note ?></span></p>
        <?php endif ?>
    </td>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

As you can see I have used a `getLabelClass()` function which I have set on the renderer object in the `_prepareForm()` function in the widget form class.

The widget form class I have used is:

```
class Kaushikamdotcom_Moduler_Block_Adminhtml_Module_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form {

protected function _prepareForm() {
    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(
        array(
            'id' => 'view_form',
            'action' => '',
            'method' => 'post'              
        )
    );


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('module_fieldset', array(
            'legend' => $this->__('Module Information'),
            'class' => 'fieldset-wide'
    ));

    $fieldset->addField('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => $this->__('Module Name'),
            'name' => 'name'
    ));

            .....etc
       }    

   public function _beforeToHtml() {
            // Instantiating renderer
        $renderer = Mage::getBlockSingleton('moduler/adminhtml_module_renderer','renderer');

                // Setting label class
        $renderer->setLabelClass('testClass');

                // Setting the renderer on the fieldset
        Varien_Data_Form::setFieldsetElementRenderer($renderer);

        parent::_beforeToHtml();
   }    
}
```

Now I have my custom label for admin fields. I hope it will help you and also invite more better answers on this question (Hence not closing it).

### 2. Second solution

Create a directory `etc` inside `app/code/local`. Then inside `app/code/local/etc` create the whole directory structure needed for `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract` class which is the parent class for all form elements. So there directory structure you need to create inside `app/code/local/etc/` is `Varien/Data/Form/Element` and then copy `Abstract.php` from `lib/Varien/Data/Form/Element/` to the directory you created. After that change the `getLabelHtml()` method as follows:

```
public function getLabelHtml() {
   if (!is_null($this->getLabel())) {
            $html = '<label for="'.$this->getHtmlId() . $idSuffix . '" class="$this->getLabelClass()">' . $this->_escape($this->getLabel())
                  . ( $this->getRequired() ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' . "\n";
        } else {
            $html = '';
        }
        return $html;
}
```

As you can see we have placed a `getLabelClass()` on the current object. So you have to use `setLabelClass($labelClass)` by iterating through `Varien_Form` object or the `fieldset` object inside you have put the field.

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't change the class, you can manipulate a label based on the 'for' attribute of the label.  Ex:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label[for=price]
    {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thats a new information